# how do i use dialog in on_enter function in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

so i want to call a dialog when i visit the screen for the first time, i did it like that:

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def dialog_close(self, *args):
        if self.dialog:
            self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
    def show_dialog(self,*args):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog=MDDialog(text="test",buttons=[MDFlatButton(text="Ok",on_release=self.dialog_close())])
        self.dialog.open()
    def on_enter(self):
        self.show_dialog()
    def Sign_In(self,*args):
        self.manager.current="main_screen"
```

but when i run this code i got error:"LoginScreen has no attribute dialog"
so i tried to declare a variable

```
dialog=None
```

before the functions,but i got an error which says that None type has no attribute dismiss, so it seems that it's not the way how is it done, then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `show_dialog()` method is calling `dialog_close()`. Try changing:

```
on_release=self.dialog_close()
```

to:

```
on_release=self.dialog_close
```

Remove the `()`.

Comment: now i get an error: AttributeError: 'LoginScreen' object has no attribute 'dialog

Comment: oh, i forgot to initialize it like dialog=None,sorry)